# I'm not a fan of [discussion], are there alternatives we could use?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I'm not a huge fan of the [discussion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag. There are only three questions tagged with it.

- [Is the idea of crowd-sourcing moderation duties a reason to prevent automated processes from helping?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/is-the-idea-of-crowd-sourcing-moderation-duties-a-reason-to-prevent-automated-pr): This is using the tag like the Meta tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
- [How can I encourage people to use the (secondary) chat feature on my community's software?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/992/how-can-i-encourage-people-to-use-the-secondary-chat-feature-on-my-communitys): This is using the tag when asking how to encourage discussions
- [Do long-term "icebreaker" threads foster quality discussion?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/986/do-long-term-icebreaker-threads-foster-quality-discussion): This is also asking how to encourage discussion

How would you like to see this tag utilized? Or, can we come up with something more relevant than "discussion" as a tag?

I realize the irony of how this question is tagged too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems like there are multiple kinds of discussion that are on topic:

- **Meta-discussion:** exactly what we're doing here! We're discussing policies for our site. We could use the tag [rules-and-policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-and-policies) and/or [feedback](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback). If those tags don't suffice, we could create a [site-discussion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-discussion) which lacks the confusion/baggage of the [discussion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.
- **Talking it out:** a form of conflict resolution where the involved parties discuss the prevalent issues. Would fall under [conflict-resolution](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-resolution).
- **Discussion as Content:** where the actual content involves discussion. Relevant tags include [content-curation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-curation) or any platform tags (e.g. [reddit](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reddit)).

The main use you mention in your post falls under the first category. In this case, a **merge** (not synonym) from [discussion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) → [site-discussion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-discussion) is all that is required (along with removing this tag from the first question). I'm saying **no** for a synonym for [discussion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) because I'd personally like to see that tag nuked and gone from the system/cache.

Comment: I'm on board with all of this.